# Is "friendly fire" session replay a valid concern?

Tags: authentication, session, client-server, cookies

I've been reading a lot about sessions and security, trying to learn as much as possible before writing too much code. I've read about limiting session replay by including a timestamp within the cookie or data sent by the server:

{timeStamp, sessionID, HMAC({timeStamp, sessionID}, Key)}

limiting the valid time with the timestamp and keeping everything over a TLS connection will minimize replay. But what happens if the user who authenticates and receives this cookie (or data) is complicit in an attack whereby he immediately sends this cookie out to others (who now have perhaps a half hour according to the timestamp). Of course, the credentials would remain limited to whatever the initial user is privileged to do.

Is this a real concern in the wild? Is there a name for it?

Is it realistic, since this is TLS, to assume the client's IP won't change, and thus use that IP as a check to make sure this cookie is always played from the IP it was originally sent to?

Answer (score 3):

The situation that you are referring to would happen if the client is compromised.  This is a real concern, but in that case any protection that you implement is trivially bypassable by having the compromised client do whatever needs to be done.  So you can do an IP address check, but it won't actually help much.

That said, the data structure that you have proposed has a red flag.  Why are you sending a timestamp to the client?  Are you going to trust what the client says?  The session ID should map to a data structure that you control which will, among other things, know when the timestamp expires.  There is therefore no need to pass that information to the client.

Comment: Sending both the sessionID and the timestamp to the client means that the client can manage state. One less thing I have to store/lookup in the server's database. I can use the included hmac to verify that nothing has been tampered with..just a quick computation.

Comment: @Dave In practice you just look up a session record, and have everything in the session.  An extra field is no noticeable extra work on top of what you are doing.  And the timestamp is very useful to have on your server side because it lets you know when you can delete expired data.  Furthermore if you start trusting the client, then you open up possible subtle attacks that you have not thought of like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack.  Don't go there.

Comment: Session times on the client can be helpful to manage server load. You can probably assume that 99% of your clients are not compromised. You still need to deal with the 1%, but that's not performance-critical anymore.

Comment: @MSalters I disbelieve.  The overhead of checking session time relative to everything else is pretty small.  If that straw breaks the camel's back, the back would break soon from something else.  And besides, everything on the server side should be designed to distribute across machines.  Then server load is easy to scale.

Comment: @btilly: It's a client latency problem. The latency of compromised clients is not performance critical.

Comment: It seems to me that client managed authentication makes it quite easy to distribute across many machines as any server can authenticate any request without need to call a particular db on a particular machine. I do, however, agree with the other assertions here on advantages of server maintained state.